# Handling checkbox selection inside Recyclerview in android

Tags: android

I am having a recycler view which contains checkboxes in items. There is a Select All button at the top. When I click on it, all the checkboxes inside recycler view , I am able to make it as checked. But the setOnCheckedChangeListener method is called only on the visible items. How can I fix this?

Comment: For the checked stage you should keep a variable as isChecked for every item in recycler view list rather than depending on setOnCheckedChangedListener. As recycler view doesn't have non visible items in memory so setOnCheckedChangedListener will never work for them.